# internal:node/x - wrong link

Tags: 8, navigation

In my Drupal 8 multilingual site I used the link field and set it to "only internal links". If I save them, I now get the following:

```
<a href="internal:/node/29" target="_blank" tabindex="0">
```

I have path, pathauto and redirect module enabled and the link is added in a custom block library block.

When I click it, it of course links to the wrong page. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem here? I can't find any other examples from people who have the same problem.

Comment: It looks like you are outputting an internal value here instead of a rendered URL... if you are using a custom Twig template (or a module that uses one) that prints this link, can you post it?